# Repairing Television in Protect-Mode

Tags: transistors, capacitor, fault

My 5-year-old television (Philips 32pfl5405h/12) stopped working two weeks ago. It seems to be in protect mode as its standby LED keeps blinking three times. 
I pulled the plug and left it for a week - no changes. I therefore assume a resistor / capacitor is broken.

As I have no experience with identifying such damages, I would like to ask you whether you can identify any broken components in the pictures attached. For me it seems there are no burned / bloated components. However, if there was an obvious flaw, I'd try to repair it on my own or consult a specialist.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks :)

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7CEV.jpg)

Comment: With no experience. Please get a certified technician to do the job.

Comment: What Jason says. And *I therefore assume a resistor / capacitor is broken.* OK, why would you think that ? *As I have no experience with identifying such damages* Aha, then again why assume that there is a resistor or capacitor broken ? Clearly you have very little knowledge about electronics. Take the TV to a professional for repair and as a bonus, avoid electrocuting yourself and/or start a fire in your house.

Comment: Don't even think of taking the cover off - if you have already then put it back on and definitely don't connect it to power without the cover in place.

Comment: Surely, I am not opening a plugged-in television. Neither have I touched any component. The whole point of asking was to find out whether (professional) repair was reasonable or if I should rather invest money in to a new device. Therefore, the first thing I did after opening it up was to ask for help identifying the damage. However, thank you for warning me - I will probably trash it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when a TV has startup issues, it is 9 times out of 10 capacitors in the power supply.

**NOTE:** Disconnect the power supply before doing ANYTHING.

**Edit from Solar Mike's suggestion:** *Make sure all capacitors are discharged before touching anything!!*

I actually had an issue with my TV not starting up a while back and it was this problem. What you should be looking for is the through-hole capacitors on the Power supply board which will be the brown coloured PCB. You should be looking for capacitors that are bulging where the 'X' on the top is, like this:
[image] You can see that the capacitors I have focused on have a bulged top. This indicates that they are broken and need to be replaced.

You have 2 choices at this stage, either buy the replacement capacitors (make a note of the value and also the voltage/temperature printed on the capacitor) and replace them yourself, or you can get someone else to fix it for you once you have identified the fault.

If you have little to no experience in electronics, and you are able to find the issue, get someone else to fix it for you or you could risk irreparable damage to the unit.

If it is not the issue described as above, and you cannot find any obvious problems (such as burnt components), then find a professional to repair it for you. This can be a difficult and/or dangerous task to someone with no experience or knowledge of electronics. If in doubt, HIRE A PROFESSIONAL.

Comment: Should you have suggested making sure capacitors are discharged????

Comment: Very good point, I'll add it to the note now. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. As I have commented on the original post I will probably throw it away as I cannot see any capacitor even remotely looking like this.